# Setting DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Valuemember to a list<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

I needed to know if one can set the ValueMember property of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn directly from a list of strings.

e.g.

```
List<string> productNames = new List<string>();

List<Products.Product> t = new List<Products.Product>();

foreach (var p in products)
{
     var x = p.Product;

     itemListing = x;

     foreach (var pn in x)
     {
         productNames.Add(pn.name);
     }
}
.............

// set values to combobox column cells in datagridview
GridSellProducts.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbItems = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)GridSellProducts.Columns["Item"];

cmbItems.DataSource = productNames;
cmbItems.DisplayMember = cmbItems.ValueMember;
cmbItems.ValueMember = // code to put here  
cmbItems.AutoComplete = true;
```

Didn't quite get the example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource.aspx

How does one set `cmbItems.ValueMember`?

Comment: Each item is a `string` so you don't need to specify any `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember`. There is only one property available here, it's the `Length` property.

Comment: Kindly show only relevant code. It makes debuggin easier for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
cmbItems.DataSource = products;
cmbItems.DisplayMember = cmbItems.ValueMember = "name";
```

Now, each item is a `Product` with a property called `name`. In your old code, it's just a string so the only possible property for DisplayMember and ValueMember is `Length`, however it's not relevant and meaningless in this case I think.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When I equate the members to "name" I get the error "Field called name does not exist."

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau isn't that your `Product` class has a property `name`? remember that you have to define some property called `name` or a better name `Name`.