# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cell value returning null value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I had posted a question last week but did not really get why I had to set a displaymember or valuemember for the first answer.

Looking at other forums, I get is that if I am using a List to be bound to a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` then I should get the selected value quite easily.

The question I posted is here:

[Setting DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Valuemember to a list<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144884/setting-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-valuemember-to-a-liststring)

I now have this code:

```
// set values to combobox column cells in datagridview
GridSellProducts.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbItems = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)GridSellProducts.Columns["Item"];

cmbItems.DataSource = productNames;

cmbItems.AutoComplete = true;

GridSellProducts.EditingControlShowing += new
            DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing);

private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string itemValue = GridSellProducts.Rows[GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Item"].FormattedValue.ToString();
.......code
}
```

However the value of string itemValue above is always null, ie string itemValue = ""; when I run my code. Why is this?

Added:

This is how I am populating productNames

```
 private void AutocompleteItems()
        {
            // get products
            productsURL = "https://eko-app.com/Products/list_products/sessionId:" + sessionID + ".json";

            var products = Products.GetProducts(productsURL);

            List<string> productNames = new List<string>();

            foreach (var p in products)
            {
                var x = p.Product;

                foreach (var pn in x)
                {
                    productNames.Add(pn.name);
                }
            }

            // set values to combobox column cells in datagridview
            GridSellProducts.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbItems = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)GridSellProducts.Columns["Item"];

            cmbItems.DataSource = productNames;

            cmbItems.AutoComplete = true;

            GridSellProducts.EditingControlShowing += new
            DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing);
        }
```

Class Products

```
//some code
public class Product
{
     public string product_id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public decimal selling { get; set; }
     public decimal buying { get; set; }
     public string default_tax_tier { get; set; }
     public string quantity_available { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. The answer is a little late but i hope it helps someone. Instead of setting the datasource of the column, I added the objects individually to the column, like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)GridSellProducts.Columns["Item"];
foreach (string productname in productNames)
{
    column.Items.Add(productname);
}
this.ValueType = typeof(string);
// if you use a custom object instead of a string, set these values:
// this.DisplayMember = "value";
// this.ValueMember = "hiddenValue";
```

Then you can get value of the object (string or something else) by getting the selecteditem from the DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl in the eventhandler. This item will be the object added to the items of the column (string in this case). The code that worked for me was:

```
private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    var currentcell = mappingDataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;

    if (currentcell.X == 0)
    {
        object value = sendingCB.SelectedItem;
        if (value != null)
        {
            string itemValue = (string)sendingCB.SelectedItem;
            //
            // or with an other object it looks like this:
            // int intValue = ((ComboBoxItem)sendingCB.SelectedItem).hiddenValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141872/event-that-fires-during-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-selectedindexchanged) post to see how to use event handlers for a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Hopefully this will help someone :).